# Problem with installed font and babel

Tags: hyphenation

I am using the fonts specified in my MWE writing usually greek. I am currently writing a document in english and I want hyphenation so I tried to use `\usepackage[english]{babel}`. Doing so I get a lot of errors. What am I doing wrong and why it doesn't work? How can I make hyphenation work?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=0.7in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*Bold,
  ItalicFont=*It,
  BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
]{GFSArtemisia}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\begin{document}

Text Here!

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{fontspec}` before the first `\setmainfont`. Also, there seems no point in setting the main font twice in the preamble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load `fontspec`. `fontspec` is a package for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX which makes it easier to select and use fonts with those engines. In particular, it defines the commands `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont`. If you do not load the package, TeX does not know what those commands mean  and it will complain that they are `undefined control sequences`. So if you wish to select fonts using these commands, you need to load the package first.

Also, it is better to load `parskip` than to manually set `parindent` to zero. And it is best to specify `british` or `american` to avoid possible disappointment.

[image: English text]

```
\documentclass[12pt,british]{article}% or american

\usepackage[top=0.7in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*Bold,
  ItalicFont=*It,
  BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
  Mapping=tex-text,
]{GFSArtemisia}% fontspec will substitute this value for the * in the definitions you specify. So you must omit the .otf extension or else TeX will look for e.g. GFSArtemisia.otfBold which you likely do not have!

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

Text Here!

\end{document}
```

Comment: In my `setmainfont` there was `GFSArtemisia.otf`. When I placed it in that code it showed me error although without it works fine. Why is that?

Comment: Also `\everymath{\displaystyle}` is disputable; actually I consider it a bad mistake.

Comment: @egreg Should it be something else? Or should it be gone?

Comment: @cfr It should be removed.

Comment: @Adam It works fine for me either way. I just removed one of the `\setmainfont` calls. If I remove the other, keeping `\setmainfont[Mapping=...]{GFS....otf}` it works fine, too.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. (You can tell how much mathematics I typeset.... I have not actually ever seen `\everymath` but if it does what it sounds as if it should, I can see why it would not be good. At least, I wouldn't use it for logic. I assume maths would be relevantly similar.)

Comment: @cfr In the code you wrote (I must mention it fixes the problem and works perfectly) I mean that if I add an .otf in the `setmainfont` then in shows me a lot of errors whereas if I remove it then it works fine!

Comment: @Adam Yes. Because you've told it to find the bold, for example, by appending `Bold` to whatever font you've specified. So the `*` gets replaced by `GFSArtemisia.otf` and TeX looks for `GFSArtemisia.otfBold` which is probably not a font you have ;).

Comment: @Adam If you leave in the extension specification in addition, it can't find even the regular as it looks for `GFSArtemisia.otf.otf`.

Comment: @ctf so I just don't add the .otf? One more thing what does the `fontspec` package do?

Comment: @Adam `fontspec` defines all of the commands you are using to select fonts (`\setmainfont`, `setsansfont` etc.). If you don't load the package, those commands are undefined.

Comment: @Adam I've added some of this to my answer for completeness. You're welcome!